# Specifying the universe of discourse

Tags: notation

Consider the following definition:

> To say that P(x) is true for every value of x in the universe of
>   discourse U, we will write $\forall x P(x)$

My question is, if I want to specifically state what the universe of discourse is, how do I express it mathematically?

For example:

$\forall x P(x)$, *where the universe of discourse is the set of all positive integers.*

How do I express "where the universe of discourse is the set of all positive integers" using mathematical notation?

Comment: If $\mathbb N$ denotes the set of positive integers then you can do it with $\forall x\in\mathbb N\;P(x)$ or $\forall x[x\in\mathbb N\implies P(x)]$

Comment: The alternative to @drhab's approach is $\forall x (x\in\Bbb N\to P(x))$, but I prefer their approach because, if your universe is already stated as $U$, you can say of some subset $S$ thereof that $\forall x (x\in S\to P(x))$.

Comment: Is ∀[∈ℕ⟹()] equivalent to ∀(∈ℕ⟹())? What I am asking is, is there any difference between square [] and round () brackets? Or they can be used interchangeably?

Comment: They can be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathbb N$ denotes the set of positive integers then you can use the expression:$$\forall x\in\mathbb N\;P(x)$$or - if you prefer an unbound quantor - the expression:$$\forall x\;[x\in\mathbb N\implies P(x)]$$

---

Caution: many mathematicians (me too) use $\mathbb N$ to denote the set of *nonnegative* integers and in order to avoid any confusion you could also use $\mathbb N^+$ or $\mathbb Z_{>0}$.